# RoR Rails 7 using Turbo to Update a partial on button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, turbo, rails7

Help!  I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails and now I'm attempting to use Rails 7 with Turbo and Stimulus to update a partial on my web page.

I have buttons on a page within a partial (call it _home.html.erb).  When clicked I'd like them to replace _home.html.erb with a different partial.

Let me show you what I've done so far:

view:

````
index.html.erb
<%= turbo_frame_tag "main-speaker-div" do %>
    <%= render partial: 'home' %>
  <% end %>```

_home.html.erb
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
        
        <%= button_to "Settings", rendersettings_path(), remote: true, class: "reader-general-button"%>

  </div>
</div>

controller:
  def rendersettings
    broadcast_replace_to "main-speaker-div", partial: 'settings'
  end
````

This code is throwing the following error:
POST 500 http://localhost:3000/rendersettings (Internal Server Error)
Response has no matching  element

Server console error:
NoMethodError (undefined method `broadcast_replace_to' for #HreaderController:0x0000000002be30):

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you following some article/guide for doing this change? I have checked the doc and it seems you need to add this `broadcast_replace_to ` method in model instead of controller.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually ended up doing the following to with my view to fix this issue:

```
<%= turbo_stream_from "main-speaker-div" %>
 <%= turbo_frame_tag "main-speaker-div" do %>
    <turbo-frame id="main-speaker-div">
    <%= render partial: 'homefull' %>
    </turbo-frame>
  <% end %>
```

It seems like if I am broadcasting I would need to have the turbo_stream_from tag added as a listener.  Please point out any issues you see with this!  I'm basically doing trial and error since this is so new to RoR

Answer (score 0):

method `broadcast_replace_to` is supposed to be called on an object of Model. I guess in your case you must have an Object of header, and this method would be called as `@header.broadcast_replace_to`